# Googlebot can't access my site when crawling from rootdomain

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I can't explain why I get this message for my rootdomain result in Google :

> trocmalin.com/
>
> A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.

Here is my site specifics :

- vide-greniers.trocmalin.com is the site address
- www.trocmalin.com redirects (301) to vide-greniers.trocmalin.com
- trocmalin.com redirects (301) to vide-greniers.trocmalin.com too...

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /orga/

  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /sitemap-update
  ```

Google results for vide-greniers.trocmalin.com are well rendered, as well as sub pages allowed for bots. But the result for my rootdomain (trocmalin.com) gives this message...

Can you help me ?

Comment: If `vide-greniers.trocmalin.com` is all OK and `trocmalin.com` redirects to this subdomain then what are you hoping to see for `trocmalin.com`?

Comment: I'd like that Google result for this address provides the same description than for vide-greniers.trocmalin.com, and not this "error" message...

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /orga
Disallow: /sitemap-update
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll let you know if it resolved my problem in 2 or 3 days.

Comment: @PéCé: You should be able to validate your robots.txt in GWT and check if any URL is blocked by it.

Comment: I've done it, and vide-greniers.trocmalin.com is OK, but trocmalin.com gives me "Out of domain"...